# For loop that counts how many characters repeat in a string, then removes the repeated characters

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

Example: attack at noon = a3t3c1k1 2n2o2

It also counts spaces.
Here is what I have, but it doesn't seem to be returning correctly:

```
String getCount(String str) {
    String R = "";
    int l = S.length();
    int cnt = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < l; j++)
            if (S.charAt(j) == S.charAt(i)) {
                cnt++;
                R = R + S.charAt(i)+""+cnt;
                System.out.print(S.charAt(i) + cnt);
            }      
    return R;
}
```

Comment: What language? You should add tags for the language. Is it #C?

Comment: The language is Java.

Comment: You are saying `S.lenght();` I think you should say `str.lenght()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getCount("attack at noon"));
}

String getCount(String str) {
        String R = "";
        String S = str;
        int l = S.length();
        int cnt;

        first:for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) { //Foreach letter
            cnt = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < l; j++) {

                if (S.charAt(j) == S.charAt(i)) {

                    if ( R.indexOf(S.charAt(j)) != -1 ) {
                        continue first;
                    }
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            R = R + S.charAt(i) + cnt; 
        }
        return R;
    }
```

> Output: a3t3c1k1 2n2o2

Comment: The output I am getting for this is a2t2c1k1

Comment: @user2957438 Besides the number mismatch you mean you don't get the last part `2n2o2`?

Comment: @user2957438 Please paste your code here http://pastie.org/ or https://gist.github.com/ and share with me the link.

Comment: @user2957438 Instead of `in.next();` try `in.nextLine();`

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are small enough you don't need anything fancy, just brute force it (for `attack at noon` this runs in 3ms).

This code will iterate over all characters, if not found before it will append the character and its count to a StringBuilder which is then printed before terminating.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Counter {
    HashMap<String, Integer> counts;
    StringBuilder result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        counter.countString("attack at noon");
    }

    void countString(String S) {
        counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        result = new StringBuilder();

        String[] split = S.split("");
        for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++) {
            String c = split[i];
            countChar(c, S);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    void countChar(String c, String s) {
        Integer integer = counts.get(c);
        if (integer == null) {
            int i = s.length() - s.replace(c, "").length();
            counts.put(c, i);
            result.append(c).append(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not removing the duplicate characters from the string.

Comment: You're right, I've changed my answer. It's also more efficient now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain a `int[]` that stores the counts of each letter in the alphabet.

```
private int[] getDuplicates(String string) {
  String str = string.toLowerCase();
  int[] charCounts = new int[27];
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c == ' ') {
      charCounts[26]++;
    }
    else {
      charCounts[c - 'a']++;
    }
  }

  return charCounts;
}
```

This method will return an array where the 0th index corresponds to the number of times 'a' shows up in your string

```
public String getCharCounts(String string) {
  int[] charCounts = getDuplicates(string);
  StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i < charCounts.length; i++) {
    if (charCounts[i] > 0) {
      char c;
      if (i < 26) {
        c = (char)(i + (int)'a');
      }
      else {
        c = ' ';
      }
      strBuff.append(c);
      strBuff.append(charCounts[i]);
    }
  }
  return strBuff.toString();
}
```

This method uses the array you get from the first method and appends the character followed by its count. This is more efficient because you only need to pass through the String one time to get the counts and then pass one time through the array to formulate your deduped String. The run-time is `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to store the counts for each character because it maintains insert order.

```
public static String countChars(String str) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for( char c : str.toCharArray() ) {
        if( map.containsKey( c ) ) {
            map.put( c, map.get( c ) + 1 );
        } else {
            map.put( c, 1 );
        }
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for( Character key : map.keySet() ) {
        sb.append(key.toString() + map.get( key ) );
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Does `Map` has a `contains` method? Also what is the `key` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my enterprise level solution

```
attack at noon = a3t3c1k1 2n2o2
```

Here's another test of the code:

```
For loop that counts how many characters repeat in a string, 
then removes the repeated characters = 
f1o6r9 15l1p3t10h6a9c5u1n5s5w1m2y1e11i2g1,1v1d1
```

And here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Counter {

    private List<CharacterCount>    characterCounts;

    public Counter() {
        this.characterCounts = new ArrayList<CharacterCount>();
    }

    public void countString(String s) {
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            CharacterCount cc = new CharacterCount(s.charAt(i));
            addCharacterCount(cc);
        }
    }

    private void addCharacterCount(CharacterCount cc) {
        for (CharacterCount count : characterCounts) {
            if (count.getCharacter() == cc.getCharacter()) {
                count.setCount(count.getCount() + 1);
                return;
            }
        }
        cc.setCount(1);
        characterCounts.add(cc);
    }

    public String returnString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (CharacterCount count : characterCounts) {
            builder.append(count.getCharacter());
            builder.append(count.getCount());
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "For loop that counts how many characters " +
                "repeat in a string, then removes the repeated " +
                "characters";
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        counter.countString(s);
        System.out.println(s + " = " + counter.returnString());
    }

    public class CharacterCount {
        private char    character;
        private int     count;

        public CharacterCount(char character) {
            this.character = character;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        public char getCharacter() {
            return character;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

```
String getGroup(final String string) {
      StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
      for(char c : string.toCharArray()) {
          int occurances = CharMatcher.is(c).countIn(string);
          if (stringBuffer.indexOf(String.valueOf(c)) == -1) {
            stringBuffer.append(String.valueOf(c) + occurances);
          }
      }
      return stringBuffer.toString();
  }
```